# Grails-Write Selenium code inside a EasyB scenario

Tags: grails, selenium, easyb

I am trying to write some selenium inside my scenario's. However, when I try to start Selenium using the following code:

```
before "start selenium", {
given "selenium is up and running", {
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",
4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.com.my/")
selenium.start()
}
```

I get an error:

```
Error running easyb tests: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed, : 7: unable to resolve class DefaultSelenium
```

I am trying to implement something like this
http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=55184

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The code you are referencing also has the following import statements:

**import com.thoughtworks.selenium.***

**import java.util.regex.Pattern**

Your error message suggests that you do not have DefaultSelenium imported in your code.